# Working with dBm using natu package in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a project where I am using the very nice [natu](https://kdavies4.github.io/natu/) package to have units on all my quantities. But now I would like to work with dBm (dB-milliwatt) which is a very common unit in microwave engineering. Anyone know if/how it is possible?

Comment: So the unit is ten times the decadic logarithm of the power divided by the reference scale of 1 mW. Since this is a non-linear unit, it likely is hard to use with common unit packages. I could imagine that you just have to convert your powers to dB_mW first and then you can attach the unit “dB” to it.

Comment: Well, the nice thing with natu is that it does support dB, so maybe there is some way to also support graded logarithmic scales.

Comment: dBm units are for power measurements, as such adding/subtracting is used instead of multiplying/dividing:  output[in Watts] = input[in Watts] * loss[unitless (or "Watts/Watts")] ==>  output[in dBm] = input[in dBm] + loss[in dB].  Note that connector/transmission loss, etc. given in dB does NOT need to be converted to dBm  to do this addition.  It would be error-prone and overly-laborious to convert from dBm/dB to milliWatts/Watts, do the multiplication, and then convert back!

Answer (score 1):

If you already have all dB(W) to obtain the equivalent dBm(W) all you have to do is to add 30.
To go back to dB(W) from dBm(W) just subtract 30.
You may also encounter dBmV or dBmA, although as default, when dealing with microwave parameters of a device, if otherwise stated dBm refers to the input power or output power, so it's ok to assume you are working with power.